# Drools horizontal scalability

Tags: drools, complex-event-processing

Does the Drools 7.x CEP support horizontal scalability to evaluate the event from Kafka stream or Redis?
Can multiple drools instances improve CEP processing performance and efficiency without business impacts?
Can the Drools work memory support to use Redis or other third-party caches?

If not, does anyone know the roadmap of Drools in which release Drools will provide these functionalities?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should check [Drools HACEP project](https://github.com/kiegroup/openshift-drools-hacep). It is a new thing started as part of the Drools ecosystem.